# How to fix seg fault when strcat two char pointers

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strcat

I get a segmentation fault because of my code with pointers. (Pointers are there needed.)

```
int main()
{    
    char *dns_name = ".";
    char *dns_name2 = ".";
    printf("HELLO\n");
    strcat(dns_name2,dns_name);
    printf("result: %s", *dns_name2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to allocate enough space to store the combined string, and you need to avoid modifying string literals.  Use a sized array for `dns_name2` at least: `char dns_name2[128] = ".";` or similar.  If you must use two `char *` values, then you'll have to store the result in an array.  Or use an array and make `dns_name2` point to it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may give that a try.
It uses dns_buffer and dns_buffer2 to create a dynamically allocated string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char *dns_name = "hh";
    char *dns_name2 = "hhha";
    char *total_dns = malloc(strlen(dns_name) + strlen(dns_name2) + 1);
    printf("HELLO\n");
    strcpy(total_dns, dns_name);
    strcat(total_dns,dns_name2);
    printf("result: %s", total_dns);

    free(total_dns);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem in your code is that the lines:

```
char *dns_name = ".";
char *dns_name2 = ".";
```

each allocate a ***fixed length*** array of characters to `dns_name` and `dns_name2`, each being two characters long (one for the dot and one for the `nul` terminator).

To fix the problem, you need to declare the strings as longer arrays, capable of holding the maximum expected length of the result of the `strcat` call:

```
char dns_name[50] = "."; // Change 50 to the maximum allowable length.
char dns_name[50] = ".";
```

Also, in your output line, you shouldn't dereference the string pointer! So, instead of:

```
printf("result: %s", *dns_name2);
```

use:

```
printf("result: %s", dns_name2); // the %s format expects a pointer or array.
```

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

EDIT: If you need `dns_name` and `dns_name2` to be actual pointers, then you can create the character arrays as separate variables and point yours to them:

```
char dns_buffer[50] = ".";
char dns_buffer2[50] = ".";
char *dns_name = dns_buffer;
char *dns_name2 = dns_buffer2;
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer